# How to give Login screen for an application which is having splitview controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

When i assign the UISplitviewController as the Rootview of the application at that time working fine,but now i want to add login screen to my application .can somebody help me thanks in advance.

Comment: are u using Tabbarcontroller?

Comment: you can temporary set an other rootVC (doing so in my apps)

Comment: no i'm not using tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Present login view controller modally

Comment: test with my answer i just testing this and post here hope it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your LoginViewcontroller as A root view-controller in Delegate ans at LoginScreen loginbutton action check userName or passowrd if it true then you have to crate object of your Delegate and set rootviewconteroller as your splitviewcontroller. like my bellow code:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[LogInViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LogInViewController" bundle:nil];


     self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

and your loginButton Action:

```
-(IBAction)loginclick:(id)sender
{
     objAppdelegate = (yourProjectnameDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
     NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

                HomeSpilitView = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

                HomeMster = [[HomeSpilitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeSpilitViewController" bundle:nil];

                masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeMster] autorelease];
                HomeMster.title=@"Title home";
                masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:0.1];
                [array addObject:masterNavigationController];


                HomeDetailsViewController *HomeDetailsViewControllers = [[HomeDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

                detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeDetailsViewControllers] autorelease];

                detailNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:0.1];
                HomeDetailsViewControllers.title=@"details title";
                HomeMster.objHomeDetailsViewcontroller=HomeDetailsViewControllers;
                HomeSpilitView.delegate = HomeDetailsViewControllers;

              [array addObject:detailNavigationController];

              [HomeSpilitView setViewControllers:array];

              [objAppdelegate.window setRootViewController:HomeSpilitView];


}
```

**UPDATE**
Finaly i done it  using  bellow code:-

```
 UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = HomeSpilitView.interfaceOrientation;
    NSString *subtypeDirection;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromTop;
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    }
    else {
        subtypeDirection = kCATransitionFromRight;
    }
    [objAppdelegate.window setRootViewController:HomeSpilitView];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:subtypeDirection];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [[objAppdelegate.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Comment: +1,Yes this one working but how to perform push operation by using like this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a newViewController then assign it as a root `ViewController`

In this `newViewController` check username and password, if it is correct then load your `splitsviewcontroller` or else show access denied message.

Comment: This is not going to work as `SplitViewController` must be your `RootViewController`...

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Says](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html) :

> The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the
>   root view of your application window. You should never present a split
>   view inside of a navigation or tab bar interface.

Use a modal view controller to present the Login view.

or Try : [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController)

Comment: we can also add splitViewcontroller as a Rootviewcontroller from login screen button click event for using object of delegate class. instaed of using Modelviewcontroller please correct me if i m wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's all are doing now a days.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your register, login Screen on a Navigation Controller
2. When you want to jump to SplitviewController , just set it as a root view controller.

   ```
   #define ApplicationDelegate  ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])


   SplitHomeViewController *objSplitHomeVC = VCWithIdentifier(@"SplitHomeViewController_iPad");
   [ApplicationDelegate.window setRootViewController:(UIViewController*)objSplitHomeVC];
   ```